# XML : GET Node values or text content for each node element by element iteratively

Tags: java, xml, dom

It may seem to be very basic problem.
But I am not clear with it yet.
Here is the issue,

I have an xml of the form :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>storm.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <name>storm-starter</name>
        <url>https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter</url>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>github-releases</id>
                <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-releases/
                </url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>clojars.org</id>
                <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </project>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi=" http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation=" http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>storm.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <name>storm-starter</name>
        <url>https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter</url>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
    </project>
</root>
```

I want to print the text content of each node one by one.
Also We assume that no tag is known before.
below is the sample code

```
public static void anotherMethod(Document doc)
{

//  NodeList nl = doc.getChildNodes();
      NodeList nodeList=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
        {
            // Get element
            Element element = (Element)nodeList.item(i);
            System.out.println(element.getNodeName()+" : "+element.getNodeValue());
        }
}
```

Here output is like :

```html
root : null
project : null
modelVersion : null
groupId : null
artifactId : null
version : null
packaging : null
name : null
url : null
properties : null
project.build.sourceEncoding : null
repositories : null
repository : null
id : null
```

But I want output should be like :

```
 modelVersion :  4.0.0
 groupId   :   storm.starter
 artifactId   :   storm-starter
 version   :    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Here it should not give me nodes which don't have text value.

I tried to replace `getNodevalue()` with `getTextContent()` but that gives all text content inside that node , including that which belongs to the sub nodes.

Please suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getTextContent()` instead of `getNodeValue()`.

```
NodeList nodeList=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (int i=0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
{
    Element element = (Element)nodeList.item(i);

    if (element.getChildNodes().getLength() == 0)
        System.out.println(element.getNodeName()+" : "+element.getTextContent());
}
```

Comment: Please see my last line that using gettextcontent() will give textcontent for all the corresponding sub nodes. So In this case it will all text corresponsing to root itself

Comment: @user3364554 Of course, it does :) If you want only text values to be written, you need to output only the text content of nodes without children. Check my update.

Answer (score 0):

Taking an Hint from the one given @Yeldar
The exact solution would be :

```
NodeList nodeList=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (int i=0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
{
  Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        if (node.getChildNodes().getLength() == 1)
        {
          System.out.println(node.getNodeName()+" : "+node.getFirstChild().getTextContent().trim());
        }
}
```

It will be able to print output like

```html
modelVersion : 4.0.0
groupId : storm.starter
artifactId : storm-starter
version : 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
packaging : jar
name : storm-starter
url : https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter
project.build.sourceEncoding : UTF-8
id : github-releases
url : http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-releases/
id : clojars.org
url : http://clojars.org/repo
groupId : junit
artifactId : junit
version : 3.8.1
scope : test
groupId : org.testng
artifactId : testng
version : 6.8.5
scope : test
groupId : org.mockito
artifactId : mockito-all
version : 1.9.0
scope : test
groupId : org.easytesting
```